# Optimal Op-amp circuit for sounder

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

I'm working on a 40kHz sounder. One pole of the piezoelectric transducer is connected to R3, other pole is connected to GND. OPAMP_OUT goes to STM32 ADC input.

Is this op-amp circuit good enough for receiving an echo from a 35W transducer from for example 10m away? The gain is OK, what I'm looking for here is that do I need more external components for reducing noise. I've seen some designs with a capacitor connected in series with the op-amp output, is that for filtering out low frequencies and would something like that be needed here? How do I improve the noise characteristics of this circuit?
[image: schematic]

Comment: It depends on whether you actually have so much out-of-band noise that it hurts your overall system's performance. Did you try your circuit? Is it working like you want? Does it have too much noise?

Comment: @JonathanS. the environment it's for doesn't have a lot of noise and the system will be powered by a 12V lead-acid battery, so pretty much no power supply noise either. I haven't tried it because building it on a breadboard will add a lot of noise because of the parasitics and a perf board will not have nearly as good grounding as a pcb does, so testing it in real life will not give accurate results. I'd like the op-amp circuit to be for the worst-case scenario noise-wise.

Comment: The thing with noise is that you don't know whether it's a problem at all before you try it. You also don't know what kind of noise (high-frequency, low-frequency, or in-band) is degrading your performance. Please build a prototype first. If it works on perfboard, you can be sure that it'll work on a proper PCB too. If it doesn't work on the perfboard, you can work out the problems there - before spending money on a real PCB. There's nothing wrong with perfboard, and at those low frequencies, you don't really have to worry about signal degradation either.